# Is it possible to make JavaScriptSerializer also populates properties without a setter?

Tags: c#, .net, json, javascriptserializer

Is it possible to make `JavaScriptSerializer` also populate properties without a setter? For example, a property like `test.ID` in the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace JavaScriptConverterTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<test> list = new List<test>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                list.Add(new test(Guid.NewGuid(), "Item #" + i));
            }
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string jsonString = serializer.Serialize(list);
            List<test> newList = serializer.Deserialize<List<test>>(jsonString);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    class test
    {
        private Guid id = Guid.Empty;

        public Guid ID
        {
            get { return id; }
            // Without a setter, JavaScriptSerializer doesn't populate this property.
            // set { id = value; }
        }
        public string name = "";

        public test()
        {
        }

        public test(Guid id, string name)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some serializes will work if you make a private setter. Other serializers allow you to use attributes so that it can write directly to the field, bypassing the property. I don't know how this one works.

Comment: @JonathanAllen, thanks, good to know, but for now I'm looking for solutions using C# build-in serializers (actually it does not have to be JSON)

Comment: I am talking about the built-in ones. Unfortunately Microsoft has made so many over the years that I can't keep them separate in my head. So the best I can offer is what to look for in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **DataContractJsonSerializer** which is built in .NET Framework and has its home at **System.Runtime.Serialization.Json**. You just need to decorate your field with **DataMemberAttribute**. Let's say you have this class:

```
class Foo
{
    private string _boo;

    public Foo(string boo) => _boo = boo;

    public string Boo => _boo;
}
```

After decorating:

```
[DataContract]
    class Foo
    {
        [DataMember] private string _boo;

        public Foo(string boo) => _boo = boo;

        public string Boo => _boo;
    }
```

And testing:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var foo = new Foo("boo");
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Foo));
            string str;
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                serializer.WriteObject(stream, foo);
                str = Encoding.Default.GetString(stream.ToArray());
            }

            Console.WriteLine(str);
            Foo loadedFoo;
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str)))
            {
                loadedFoo = serializer.ReadObject(stream) as Foo;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(loadedFoo.Boo);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

The **loadedFoo** that is constructed from the json string gets "boo" as value for **_boo** field.